# Command line program to Check Number of Seeder on a Torrent

Tags: bittorrent

is there a command line program that could check number of available seeder (and peers) for one or more torrent file, something that could give an output like this:

```
# peercount *.torrent
12/136 a.torrent 
0/3 b.torrent
40/2 c.torrent
```

12, 0 and 40 for number of seeder

136, 3 and 2 for number of peer

a, b and c for the torrent file name

I need this to delete torrent files that has very little chance to complete

Comment: It's not bittorent, but look at [Extending Transmission using Scripts](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/Scripts).

Comment: try using aria2 with verbose switch

Comment: What are "leechers" in this context? The term used to be used for people who downloaded from FTP servers without uploading anything first. In torrents, people who are in the process of downloading are "peers", those who have downloaded and are now sharing are "seeders". "Leechers" would be people who have blocked their upload but are still downloading, is that what you mean? Also, do you want the total number of seeds/peers or the number you are currently connected to?

Comment: I would guess that the most flexible way is to use a client which has a web interface then write a script which parses the webpage for the data you need. This type of system would work with most clients and it'd be fairly easy to implement. I can't show you how though because it is completely client dependent and I have no idea what client you use.

Comment: Ok, i,ve revise my question, what i mean is the peer not leecher. Seed/peer that available on all trackers

Comment: I use windows version of uTorrent on archlinux